# Given a Parallellogram $OACB$, How to Evaluate $\vec{OC}.\vec{OB}$?

Tags: geometry, vectors

**Question**

Given a parallellogram $OACB$. The lengths of the vectors $\vec{OA},\vec{OB}  \ \text{and}\ \vec{AB}$ are $a,b$ and $c$ respectively. The scalar product of the vectors $\vec{OC}$ and $\vec{OB}$ is

$(A)\frac{a^2-3b^2+c^2}{2}\hspace{1cm}(B)\frac{3a^2+b^2-c^2}{2}\hspace{1cm}(C)\frac{3a^2-b^2+c^2}{2}\hspace{1cm}(D)\frac{a^2+3b^2-c^2}{2}$

---

**My Attempt**:

Let $O$ be $(0,0,0)$,position vector of $A$ be $\vec{a}$,position vector of $B$ be $\vec{b}$ and position vector of $C$ is $\vec{a}+\vec{b}$. Next, I write

$$\vec{OC}.\vec{OB}=|\vec{OC}||\vec{OB}|\cos\angle BOC$$

but here I am stuck. I don't know the angle $\angle BOC$!

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the law of cosines,
$$\cos\angle{AOB}=\frac{|\vec{OA}|^2+|\vec{OB}|^2-|\vec{AB}|^2}{2|\vec{OA}||\vec{OB}|}=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$$

So,
$$\begin{align}\vec{OC}\cdot\vec{OB}&=(\vec{OA}+\vec{OB})\cdot\vec{OB}\\\\&=\vec{OA}\cdot\vec{OB}+|\vec{OB}|^2\\\\&=|\vec{OA}||\vec{OB}|\cos\angle{AOB}+b^2\\\\&=ab\cdot\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}+b^2\\\\&=\frac{a^2+3b^2-c^2}{2}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no need to **memorize the cosine law**. Put the origin of the coordinate system at **O**, then we can write

$$\mathop {OB}\limits^ \to  .\mathop {OC}\limits^ \to   = {\bf{B}}.{\bf{C}} = {\bf{B}}.\left( {{\bf{A}} + {\bf{B}}} \right) = {\bf{A}}.{\bf{B}} + {\bf{B}}.{\bf{B}} = {\bf{A}}.{\bf{B}} + {b^2}\tag{1}$$

so, your main task will be to compute ${\bf{A}}.{\bf{B}}$, you can do it as follows

$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {AB}\limits^ \to  .\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to   = \left( {{\bf{B}} - {\bf{A}}} \right).\left( {{\bf{B}} - {\bf{A}}} \right) = {\bf{A}}.{\bf{A}} + {\bf{B}}.{\bf{B}} - 2{\bf{A}}.{\bf{B}}  \cr 
  & {c^2} = {a^2} + {b^2} - 2{\bf{A}}.{\bf{B}}  \cr 
  & {\bf{A}}.{\bf{B}} = \frac{{{a^2} + {b^2} - {c^2}}}{2} \cr}\tag{2}$$

Now, combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get

$$\mathop {OB}\limits^ \to  .\mathop {OC}\limits^ \to   = \frac{{{a^2} + {b^2} - {c^2}}}{2} + {b^2} = \frac{{{a^2} + 3{b^2} - {c^2}}}{2}\tag{3}$$

Comment: @Vinod Kumar Punia: See this answer. Memorize less, Analyze more! :)

Comment: Good solution. It looks to me like you don't even have to assume a coordinate system. Just rename the vectors $OC = C$, $OA = A$ and so on and the same calculations apply.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: Thanks. :) I think you are right. :)